# SCSS lint Install and configuration on Angular cli

Tags: angular, scss-lint

Trying to configure the SCSS lint on my angular cli app, while installing the scss lint module getting the below errors, does the scss lint needed python too?

I have a python installed on my machine in globally, I can execute the python from anywhere like D:> python => It's working.

> is there any other module is usefull to validate the scss?

```
D:\MyApp>npm install scsslint --save
npm WARN deprecated win-spawn@2.0.0: use [cross-spawn](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn) or [cross-spawn-async](https://github.com/IndigoUnited/node-cross-spawn-async) instead.

> farmhash@1.2.1 install D:\MyApp\node_modules\farmhash
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\MyApp\node_modules\farmhash>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\gk022017\sgwt-installer\nodist\npmv\4.6.1\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\gk022017\sgwt-installer\nodist\npmv\4.6.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:482:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gk022017\sgwt-installer\nodist\npmv\4.6.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\gk022017\sgwt-installer\nodist\npmv\4.6.1\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\gk022017\\sgwt-installer\\nodist\\v-x64\\8.9.4\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\gk022017\\sgwt-installer\\nodist\\npmv\\4.6.1\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\MyApp\node_modules\farmhash
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> integer@1.0.3 install D:\MyApp\node_modules\integer
> node tools/install


D:\MyApp\node_modules\integer>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\gk022017\sgwt-installer\nodist\npmv\4.6.1\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\gk022017\sgwt-installer\nodist\npmv\4.6.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:482:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\gk022017\sgwt-installer\nodist\npmv\4.6.1\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Users\gk022017\sgwt-installer\nodist\npmv\4.6.1\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Users\\gk022017\\sgwt-installer\\nodist\\v-x64\\8.9.4\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\gk022017\\sgwt-installer\\nodist\\npmv\\4.6.1\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\MyApp\node_modules\integer
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
gyp ERR! not ok
hola@0.0.0 D:\MyApp
`-- scsslint@0.0.3

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\MyApp\node_modules\tsickle\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\MyApp\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin\package.json'
npm WARN @schematics/package-update@0.3.2 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/core@0.3.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @schematics/package-update@0.3.2 requires a peer of @angular-devkit/schematics@0.3.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN ngx-breadcrumbs@0.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=4.0.0 <5.0.0 || >=4.0.0-beta <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN ngx-breadcrumbs@0.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/router@>=4.0.0 <5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN The package @angular/animations is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package font-awesome is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: farmhash@1.2.1 (node_modules\farmhash):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: farmhash@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: integer@1.0.3 (node_modules\integer):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: integer@1.0.3 install: `node tools/install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

Comment: so the executable's path you see in your error message does exists? `C:\HOMEWARE\Anaconda3-Windows-x86_64\python.EXE`?

Comment: Yes, in the same path python files are located.